# how to Add text fields, radio buttons and select dropdown to Froala toolbar

Tags: angular, editor, field, froala

I need some help with froala editor, how to add text fields, radio buttons and select dropdown to Froala toolbar.

I need to show some popup where we can enter the data related with the fields.
Can some one help me ?

I tried creating a custom button with which I can insert html but I need to show a popup when I can provide the filed name, label,  or list of  options incase of select drop down. this.